# submenu not displaying... any ideas?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i'm reverse engineering an actionscript based site for one of my clients.  so, i've got this problem... i asked a question earlier and got a response that has led me to this one...

i have an array:

```
subnavData = new Array(
                {"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showServices, "hasChild":true},
                    {"title":"CREATIVE DIRECTION", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showBranding, "childOf":0},
                    {"title":"SOCIAL INTERACTIVE", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showOnline, "childOf":0},
                    {"title":"LIVE EVENTS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showLiveEvents, "childOf":0},
                    {"title":"CONTENT STRATEGY", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showPerformance, "childOf":0},
                {"title":"PROCESS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showProcess},
                {"title":"CASE STUDIES", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showCaseStudies},
                {"title":"CLIENTS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showClients}
            );
```

that gets built into a menu by this function:

```
private function makeNewSubNav($data:Array):void {
            group = new Array();
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < $data.length; i++){
                var obj:Object = new Object();
                obj.active = false;
                obj.mc = new MovieClip();
                if($data[i].childOf != undefined) {
                    obj.childOf = $data[i].childOf;
                    obj.mcB = new SubMenuTopButton();
                    obj.mcB.arrow.x = -obj.mcB.arrow.width;
                    obj.mcB.txtmask.x += 10;
                    obj.mcB.y = group[obj.childOf].subMasked.height;
                    var childbg:Sprite = new Sprite();
                    childbg.graphics.beginFill(0xfdddf0, 1);
                    childbg.graphics.lineStyle();
                    childbg.graphics.drawRect(0,0,167, 21);
                    childbg.graphics.endFill();
                    obj.mcB.addChildAt(childbg, 0);
                    group[obj.childOf].subMasked.addChild(obj.mc);
                } else {
                    obj.childOf = false;
                    obj.mcB = new SubMenuTopButton();
                    navContainer.addChild(obj.mc);
                }
                obj.mc.addChild(obj.mcB);
                obj.mcB.txtmask.tf_name.text = $data[i].title;
                obj.mcB.buttonMode = true;
                obj.mcB.mouseChildren = false;
                obj.mcB.num = i;
                obj.callback = $data[i].func;
                obj.param = $data[i].param;
                obj.mcB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, navPress);
                obj.mcB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, navOver);
                obj.mcB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, navOut);

                if($data[i].hasChild != undefined){
                    obj.hasChild = true;
                    obj.subContainer = new MovieClip();
                    obj.subMasked = new MovieClip();
                    obj.subMask = new MovieClip();
                    obj.subMask.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF,1);
                    obj.subMask.graphics.lineStyle();
                    obj.subMask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,width,1);
                    obj.subMask.graphics.endFill();
                    obj.subMask.height = 0;
                    obj.subContainer.addChild(obj.subMasked);
                    obj.subContainer.addChild(obj.subMask);
                    obj.subMasked.mask = obj.subMask;
                    obj.subContainer.y = obj.mc.height;
                    obj.mc.addChild(obj.subContainer);
                }
                group.push(obj);
            }

            adjustHeight();

        }
```

but the 'childOf' never gets rendered.  know what's going on?  any help is greatly appreciated.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified and tested your code locally.  The buttons were created correctly, but remained hidden.  You need to resize your SubMask after you have created a new SubButton, otherwise its height will always stay 0, and none of your buttons will be displayed.  Also, the y-positioning seems to be off.